# Dividing two int values in SQL. As a result I am getting int result instead of float

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Sorry for complete newbie question.

I have Azure SQL database. In this database I have two columns with two `int` values. Result should not be `int` but `float`. For example: I divide 8 by 141. I always get 0.

Can someone suggest me what I am doing wrong. I don't know to define new column as float, because I am using calculated column. I even tried with:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bmw] ADD consumption AS ([fuelLevel]/[range]*100) PERSISTED
```

But still result is 0:

I am dividing 8 and 141, I would expect to get value of 0.0567

Comment: Integer division? Try 1.0 * fuellevel etc.

Comment: Why would you expect anything else other than an `int` when only `int` values are involved? Data types of expressions don't change if only one data type is involved; much like `'abc' + 'def'` won't result in `N'abcdef'`, or `100.00+100.00` won't result in `2e2`. SQL Server respects strick typing.

Comment: @Larnu: Well, 8 divided by 141 is 0.0567 not 0, so obviously a division of two integers can result in a decimal vaue. It is not at all wrong to assume this. Lesson learnt for Rok Rogelj is that some DBMS apply kindergarten math when it comes to integers. I was surpised just the same when it happened to me the first time I came across such a DBMS.

Comment: jarlh, thank you for your suggestion. I used: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bmw] ADD consumption AS (1.00*[fuelLevel]/[range]*100) PERSISTED and now I am getting float. Just one small additional question. How can I round it on two decimals, because now I am getting 13 decimals.

Comment: @Rok Rogelj: Surprisingly you can round numbers with `ROUND` :-) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Just note that normally you don't want to be using *float* to represent decimal values, use the specifically named *decimal* or *numeric* types

Comment: @ThorstenKettner *"obviously a division of two integers can result in a decimal vaue"* no, like I said, if you only have `int` values getting a `decimal` value makes little sense; if you want a `decimal` value obviously you need to work in `decimal` data types. It not "kindergarten" maths, nor is it unique to DBMS, it simply *good* and strict data typing. If you had 2 `int` values like you did there and did the same division in C#, Java or Go you would also get `0`; `0.0567` can't be represented as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a result with decimals, you have to convert at least one of the values you are dividing by to a decimal/float data type.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bmw] ADD consumption AS (CAST([fuelLevel] AS DECIMAL (9,2))/[range]*100) PERSISTED
```

Comment: Ok, this is clear, but how can I ingest ROUND() into this command, if I ant to have result in 2 decimals instead of 13?

Comment: Did you try adding the round function already? If so, what was the error?